# Is there a way to check a mesh for problems?

Tags: mesh, export, vertices

Is there a way in Blender to check a mesh for missing or duplicate faces, mesh abnormalities, or other issues that might cause problems when it is exported and used as data for a real-time application such as a game?

Comment: Only your last sentence is valid, since everything else is a bug report or not tied to blender itself. There is probably a problem in the export/import procedure or the script itself.

Comment: If the details don't pertain to Blender, should I remove it or is it still a legit question for the site?

Comment: Would be good if you could elaborate more and expand your last sentence. Like what needs to be checked and how the mesh should look like for your export script to accept it and export correctly. More people will be able to help, this is too specific otherwise

Comment: Apparently others think the question should be closed. I'll just look elsewhere for an answer. Thanks anyway, Jerryno.

Comment: The question body is worded fine, but I would change the question itself to get rid of the Fallout reference. Basically I think Omegacron is looking for a tool like MeshLint: http://www.blendernation.com/2014/07/30/blender-addon-overview-mesh-lint/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an addon called Mesh Lint that allows you to check a mesh for several of the problems that might cause issues in games. You can find more information about it here:
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/MeshLint

It should still work with current (2.7x) versions of Blender, although it is not included, so you will need to download it from the link above and install it manually (user File > User Preferences... > Addons > Install from File...)

There is a video about how to use it here: http://cgcookie.com/blender/2013/07/23/addon-mesh-lint/

Comment: The video link is broken.

Comment: Neither of these links work anymore.

Comment: Is there any new addon's/methods

Answer (score 10):

There's an old way. In edit mode, select nothing with <kbd>A</kbd> and then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> to select non manifold verts or edges. These are edges that do not have exactly two faces connected to them. If nothing gets selected, your mesh is pretty solid.

Try it with vertex select or edge select. Both modes provide insight.

Comment: The key combination is atrocious, but that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Cool. One is glad to be of service. Manifold is not completely foolproof but it's helpful. Shortcut remedies: assign another shortcut. A bit hard since there's few left. Use the space bar and type mani in it. Or create a button to click on. That's much simpler than one would think.

Comment: This does not work anymore in Blender 2.8. The key combination does nothing (I tested by manually creating an edge with 3 faces).

Comment: 2.8 is still a hated mystery to me.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the mesh lint answer I provided above, Blender also has a couple of functions that can help solve common problems. I recently switched to Blender for game work and these are the functions I have found to be invaluable for preparing mesh for export.

**Remove duplicates / merge vertices**: To remove duplicate faces, vertices or edges in a mesh, enter Edit mode, select everything and press <kbd>W</kbd> to bring up the specials menu. From this menu select *Remove Doubles* (or press 4) and any duplicate elements will be removed.

*Note*: this function will also merge vertices that are in the same spot or very close together; the threshold can be configured by changing the *Merge distance* setting located in the Last Operator panel in the Toolshelf (or press <kbd>F6</kbd> after operation executing).

**Select Linked**: You can select all parts of a mesh that are linked together by selecting one part and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. If you then invert the selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, you can find any unwanted loose polygons.

**Select Loose Geometry**: This will select single mesh elements that are not connected to others, such as floating vertices, edges and faces. Note that you need to be in vertex edit to select vertices, edge to select edges and face to select floating faces, and it won't work if there is more than one element connected together, which is why I prefer Select Linked.

**Apply Transform**: You can apply (or freeze) any transform on a mesh by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and selecting the desired option. This can help to fix problems with scale / rotation after export.

**Move Pivot**: You can move the object pivot with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. The pivot can be moved to the 3D Cursor, which can be moved exactly with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or by entering a position in the Properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) in the 3D view. This can fix problems with a model being in an unexpected position or rotation after exporting.

Comment: Remove doubles is one I use systematically. Also convert to triangles before exporting as engines work with triangles, even if they accept quads they will probably triangulate while loading. It's better to see the triangulated version in Blender prior to export.

Comment: W no longer brings up the specials menu in Blender 2.8 (instead it just changes the select mode).

Answer (score 2):

Yo Omegacron!
Blender also has a cleanup function. It has some functions that are similar to the CleanUp in Maya like 'generate dissolve' (deletes zero length faces and edges, also double faces)
You can find it if you go to Edit Mode and to Mesh -> CleanUp in the 3D View Header. Make sure you selected the whole mesh before you clean up, generate dissolve, delete loose and fill holes should make your mesh game-ready :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the 3D-Print toolbox add-on.

[image]

Open the Analize tab and use the Check All to find problems like intersecting Faces, Non manifold Geometry, Non Plannar Faces, etc.

Some of the problems you can fix with the Clean Up tool.

[image]

Comment: This tool was exactly what I was looking for. Thin faces in particular let me find crossed planes that cause problems in prints.