# Why subdivision surface modifier bridges unrealted and distant vertices

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I have already elimintated doubles and revised all the vertices and faces, moved them around and back in place to ensure there are not hidden unwanted elements in my mesh [and it seems clean to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDSY1.png)

However when I include a subdivision surface modifier, it bridges with edges totally distant and unrelated vertices, even if i switch from catmull-clark to simple. [image: i have been screwing my brain for hours and i give up].

Comment: this is a way to check a mesh for problems :(the answer by Haunt_House)
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47034/68052

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/